# Why scipy.integrate.quad returning odd values for integration of a normalised sinc function instead of 1 in python?

Tags: python, scipy

While I was trying to approximate a normalised sinc function as a delta function and integrate it using quad from -infinity to infinity , it is returning me some erronous results. Same happens if I use simps splitting up the integral on both sides of discontinuity. Couldn't figure out what's happening. Any help appreciated.
Here is the code:
'''

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import.quad

sigma=eval(input('Enter sigma i.e.         
width: '))
mu=eval(input('Enter the shifted x- 
coordinate: ')) # Point of peak value
delta3=lambda x: 1/(np.sqrt(2*np.pi)*sigma)*np.exp((-(x-mu)**2)/(2*sigma**2))
delta3=np.vectorize(delta3)

xp=np.linspace(mu-np.inf,np.inf,1000)
I=simps(f(xp)*delta3(xp),xp)
print('Value of Integration: ',format(I,'0.7f'))
```

'''

Comment: For demo purposes hardocde `sigma` and `mu`; don't use `input`.  Why are you using `vectorize`?  The `lambda` evaluates on an array just fine.  The `linspace` on `inf` range doesn't make sense.  In short we need a [mcve].

Comment: With `mu=0` and `sigma=1`, `quad` on a (-5,5) interval is plenty close to 1.